# ConstraintLayout: Realign baseline constraint in case if dependent view visibility was set to GONE

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Is there any way to realign baseline constraint for the TextView in case if dependent view visibility was set to GONE?

My layout code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST TITLE"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SUBTITLE 1"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/subtitle2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/subtitleSpace"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/subtitleSpace"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/subtitle1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/subtitle2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="SUBTITLE 2"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/subtitleSpace"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In this case, my layout looks like this:
[image]

When I'm setting `subtitle2` TextView visibility to `GONE` my layout will look like this:
[image]

So I'm wondering if there is some constraint which can realign baseline in the case if the dependent view is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate margins can be specified for `GONE` widgets (see [Margins when connected to a GONE widget](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#GoneMargin)), but I am not aware of such an alternative for baselines.

One way to satisfy your requirement is to specify a `0dp` invisible `TextView` that has the same characterisics of the `GONE` `TextView` that is placed next to that same view. `subtitle1` and `subtitle2` would tie to the baseline of this new `TextView`. Even though the new `TextView` doesn't show on the screen and takes zero width, it still maintains a baseline.

Now, when `subtitle2` is made `GONE`, `subtitle1` will move to the center but maintain its vertical position. (Specifying `0dp` and `invisible` with null text is redundant but makes it clear that the widget should not appear.)

Here is the XML with these changes:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST TITLE"
        android:textColor="#FF000000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SUBTITLE 1"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/viewForBaseline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/subtitleSpace"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/subtitleSpace"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/subtitle1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/subtitle2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="SUBTITLE 2"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/viewForBaseline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/subtitleSpace"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewForBaseline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I already applied the same solution as you proposed but still was wondering if there are some constraints for `GONE` text view baselines. I don't really want to leave empty views in my layout to avoid complications and keep it cleaner.

Comment: I think the answer to that question is that there is not, but it would make sense to have such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically, outside of xml code. It's not ideal solution but you end up with exact set of constrain you want. Base idea:

```
private val defaultConstrainSet = ConstraintSet()
private val newConstrainSet = ConstraintSet()

init {
    defaultConstrainSet.clone(constraintLayout)
    newConstrainSet.apply {
        clone(constraintLayout)
        // here put your new constrains, eg. :
        clear(R.id.subtitle1, ConstraintSet.BASELINE)
        connect(R.id.agenda_index, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.title, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
    }
}
```

and then

```
    if (/* subtitle2 is visible */) {
        defaultConstrainSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)
    } else {
        newConstrainSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)
    }
```